# Can i force QFileDialog to use system locale instead of system language?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Can i force QFileDialog to use system locale instead of system language?
For example: I have english language installed on my system as System Language (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language) and French as System Locale (Control Panel\Region\Administrative\Change system locale).

So the question is: is it possible to force QFileDialog to use French language instead of English for translating controls? 
Probably i should use WinApi?

Answer (score 0):

The system locale is for applications that do not support unicode and they get loaded with an ANSI code page that the locale says. For the rest of the applications, this setting has no meaning.

This has no effect on the common dialogs. For these you cannot set the language because this is a per-user account setting. Even if there was such an option, it wouldn't consider the system locale.

Your only bet is to create the dialog yourself manually.